# How to atomically add and fetch a 128-bit number in C++?

Tags: c++, atomic

I use Linux x86_64 and clang 3.3.

Is this even possible in theory?

`std::atomic<__int128_t>` doesn't work (undefined references to some functions).

[`__atomic_add_fetch`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) also doesn't work ('error: cannot compile this atomic library call yet').

Both `std::atomic` and `__atomic_add_fetch` work with 64-bit numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with a single instruction, but you can emulate it and still be lock-free. Except for the very earliest AMD64 CPUs, x64 supports the `CMPXCHG16B` instruction. With a little multi-precision math, you can do this pretty easily.

I'm afraid I don't know the instrinsic for `CMPXCHG16B` in GCC, but hopefully you get the idea of having a spin loop of `CMPXCHG16B`. Here's some untested code for VC++:

```
// atomically adds 128-bit src to dst, with src getting the old dst.
void fetch_add_128b(uint64_t *dst, uint64_t* src)
{
    uint64_t srclo, srchi, olddst[2], exchlo, exchhi;

    srchi = src[0];
    srclo = src[1];
    olddst[0] = dst[0];
    olddst[1] = dst[1];

    do
    {
        exchlo = srclo + olddst[1];
        exchhi = srchi + olddst[0] + (exchlo < srclo); // add and carry
    }
    while(!_InterlockedCompareExchange128((long long*)dst,
                                          exchhi, exchlo,
                                          (long long*)olddst));

    src[0] = olddst[0];
    src[1] = olddst[1];
}
```

**Edit:** here's some untested code going off of what I could find for the GCC intrinsics:

```
// atomically adds 128-bit src to dst, returning the old dst.
__uint128_t fetch_add_128b(__uint128_t *dst, __uint128_t src)
{
    __uint128_t dstval, olddst;

    dstval = *dst;

    do
    {
        olddst = dstval;
        dstval = __sync_val_compare_and_swap(dst, dstval, dstval + src);
    }
    while(dstval != olddst);

    return dstval;
}
```

Comment: Why did you have to post that, makes my inline assembler look so rubbish ;)

Comment: Hah! Well, VC++ optimizes that code like rubbish and supports no inline asm for 64-bit so don't feel bad.

Answer (score 4):

Yes; you need to tell your compiler that you're on hardware that supports it.

This answer is going to assume you're on x86-64; there's likely a similar spec for arm.

From the generic x86-64 [microarchitecture levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels), you'll want at least `x86-64-v2` to let the compiler know that you have the `cmpxchg16b` instruction.

Here's a working godbolt, note the compiler flag `-march=x86-64-v2`:
https://godbolt.org/z/PvaojqGcx

For more reading on the x86-64-psABI, the spec is published [here](https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI/-/wikis/x86-64-psABI).

Answer (score 2):

That isn't possible. There is no x86-64 instruction that does a 128-bit add in one instruction, and to do something atomically, a basic starting point is that it is a single instruction (there are some instructions which aren't atomic even then, but that's another matter).

You will need to use some other lock around the 128-bit number.

Edit: It is possible that one could come up with something that uses something like this:

```
 __volatile__ __asm__(
    "     mov            %0, %%rax\n"
    "     mov            %0+4, %%rdx\n"
    "     mov            %1,%%rbx\n"
    "     mov            %1+4,%%rcx\n"
    "1:\n
    "     add            %%rax, %%rbx\n"
    "     adc            %%rdx, %%rcx\n"
    "     lock;cmpxcchg16b %0\n"
    "     jnz            1b\n"
    : "=0"
    : "0"(&arg1), "1"(&arg2));
```

That's just something I just hacked up, and I haven't compiled it, never mind validated that it will work. But the principle is that it repeats until it compares equal.

Edit2: Darn typing too slow, Cory Nelson just posted the same thing, but using intrisics.

Edit3: Update loop to not unnecessary read memory that doesn't need reading... CMPXCHG16B does that for us.

Comment: your statement "to do something atomically, a basic starting point is that it is a single instruction" is inaccurate.   It either (1) needs to be a single instruction, or (2) the processor needs to support operations such as LL/SC or CMPXCHG or hardware transactional memory, that allow lock-free spinloops using these operations to be used to create more complicated atomic operations.  Or (3) you need to using a locking protocol.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, do you need a `lock` in front of the `cmpxcchg16b`?

Comment: @ergohack: I think you are right, I've added a lock.