# c++: Atomicity test for 128 bit compare and swap

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, atomic

I am trying to verify the atomicity of 128 bit operations on different intel CPUs but for some reason my program is failing atomicity test on every machine I test. I have tested on ivy bridge, and broadwell CPUs. I have included the source code below. Basically it is incrementing two 64 bit counters simultaneously which are combined together to form the 128 bit integer. If atomicity is working on the CPU then the lower 64 bits must be equal to the upper 64 bits, always. And thats what this program is testing. But the test is failing all the time with the output:

> Found inconsistency 18550, 18551

I am running ubuntu 4.15, gcc I am compiling this code as:

`g++ -pthread -march=native test.cc -latomic`

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <thread>

__int128 __attribute__((__aligned__(16))) count;

void task() {
 while(1) {
  __int128 old_count, swapped_count;
  do {
    __atomic_load(&count, &old_count, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    uint64_t old_lo = (uint64_t)old_count;
    uint64_t old_hi = ((uint64_t)(old_count >> 64));
    if (old_lo != old_hi) {
      printf("Found inconsistency %lu, %lu\n", old_lo, old_hi);
      exit(1);
    }
    __int128 __attribute__((__aligned__(16))) new_count;
    new_count = old_hi + 1;
    new_count <<= 64;
    new_count |= (old_lo + 1);
    swapped_count = __sync_val_compare_and_swap(&count, old_count, new_count);
    uint64_t new_lo = (uint64_t)swapped_count;
    uint64_t new_hi = (uint64_t)(swapped_count >> 64);
    if (new_lo != new_hi) {
      printf("Found inconsistency post swap %lu, %lu\n", new_lo, new_hi);
      exit(1);
    }
    // At this point count must have changed one way or the other
    if (count == old_count) {
      printf("Count is still the same ????\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }  while (old_count != swapped_count);
 }  // while (1)
}

int main() {
  count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    new std::thread(task);

  while(1)
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: What do you see?  How does it fail?

Comment: I hit that printf where it says "found inconsistency" i.e. the upper 64 bits are not the same as lower 64 bits. Which indicates that the 128 bits were not updated atomically.

Comment: `on different intel CPUs ` Which CPUs?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177622/how-to-atomically-add-and-fetch-a-128-bit-number-in-c ?

Comment: Kamil, I did mention Ivy bridge and Broadwell. Also, I do not think it is a duplicate of the other post.

Comment: I would avoid mixing __sync and __atomic builtins.

Answer (score 2):

So What I found is that gcc does not implement 16Byte atomics in a lock free manner. After some debugging with gdb, I found that the __atomic*_16() functions in gcc, use a lock. On the other hand __sync*_16() functions use `lock cmpxchg16` instruction. So Marc's suggestion is right. You cannot mix __sync with __atomic and in general __atomic (specially for 16 byte ops) are not lock free (yet ?).

So I ended up implementing my own primitives for 16 byte atomic load and CAS. I am pasting that code below. Using those primitives, the above code just works.

```
union alignas(16) atomic_u128 {
  unsigned __int128 val;
  struct {
    volatile uint64_t lo, hi;
  };
};

// Atomically read a 128 bit unsigned.
__attribute__((always_inline)) inline unsigned __int128 AtomicLoad128(
    register atomic_u128 *src) {
  atomic_u128 ret;
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
      "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n"
      "xor %%eax, %%eax\n"
      "xor %%edx, %%edx\n"
      "xor %%ebx, %%ebx\n"
      "lock cmpxchg16b %2"
      : "=&a"(ret.lo), "=d"(ret.hi)
      : "m"(*src)
      : "cc", "rbx", "rcx" );
  return ret.val;
}

__attribute__((always_inline)) inline bool AtomicCAS128(
    volatile atomic_u128 *src, atomic_u128 *expected,
    atomic_u128 desired) {
  bool result;
  atomic_u128 e;
  e.val = expected->val;
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "lock cmpxchg16b %1"
    : "=@ccz" ( result ), "+m" ( *src ), "+a"(e.lo), "+d"(e.hi)
    : "c" ( desired.hi ), "b" ( desired.lo )
    : "cc");
  if (!result)
    expected->val = e.val;

  return result;
}
```