# Is it possible to get an atomic __int128 in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, integer, atomic

I'm trying to work with atomic numbers and big ints. I'm using gcc and found it had an `__int128` type, which is perfect, but how can I get an atomic one? I can't get an `atomic_int128` or the like nor an `atomic<__int128>` to work.

Comment: On what architecture?  Some may not even have the necessary instructions.

Comment: this seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177622/how-to-atomically-add-and-fetch-a-128-bit-number-in-c

Comment: Why do you think `atomic<__int128>` doesn't work?

Comment: Compiles for me live - https://godbolt.org/z/3veqGh

Comment: @RichardCritten not very easy to use https://godbolt.org/z/1Mb5z5

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili thanks for finding that